# do i need an ssl certificate for testing environment on subdomain?

Tags: ssl, subdomain, development-environment

I can't use my SSL certificate on subdomains because it is for the top level domain `www.tld.com` only. When I force it on a subdomain e.g. `dev.tld.com` I get a warning.

What I want to achieve is a development subdomain on the same shared hosting webspace where I can test under real conditions, especially concerning payment systems where an SSL connection is mostly mandatory.

My question is: Do I have to get an extra certificate or is it possible to just `click the warning away` and make use of https? Am I obliged to buy a certificate in order to use SSL technically? At least it seems to work once I've told my browser to trust the subdomain ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is telling you that the domain name listed in the certificate does not match the domain name you browsed to.  You will still have an SSL connection.  Since you are the one that configured the environment, you can ignore the warning.

Having said that, a wildcard SSL certificate is not much more expensive than one for a single domain (shop around!).  I would suggest your next SSL certificate be for a wildcard domain (*.tld.com).  That will avoid the issue of the warning entirely.

Comment: Thanks for your soon answer Eric. This sounds logical to me now but actually I couldn't find any information about that.